# How to iterate and increase a counter in SPSS?

Tags: count, statistics, spss

I want to do count educational advancement in my dataset in SPSS. I have some programming experience, but I am stuck with the syntax.

I have a variable my_education. I want to iteratively compare `my_education` with `education_father` and `education_mother`. If `my_education` is bigger than that of my parents, i have an advancement, if not, well not an advancement. All variables are numerically coded.

```
advancement = 0
regress = 0

if my_education > max(education_father, education_mother) advancement ++1
```

(i tried ++1 or +1 but it doesnt work)

At the end, i expect a variable like advancement to be something like 340 and regress to be 190, let's say.

I guess the main issue is how to use the code to iterate through the whole dataset and increase the counter at the end. Can anyone help me out here?

EDIT:

I also tried this :

```
do if (my_education > max(education_mother &education_father)).
Compute advancement =1. -> i want this variable to increase though
Else if (my_education < max(education_mother &education_father)).
Compute regress =1. -> same here, to give the exact number of increases or regresses
```

EDIT2 : and this :

```
if (my_education > max(education_mother,education_father)) achievement=1.
if (my_education < max(education_mother,education_father)) achievement=2.
if (my_education = max(education_mother,education_father)) achievement=3.
freq achievement.
```

But there are still many cases not counted, something like 70% of all cases. Also, if I swap MAX with MIN, i get the same number of cases.

Comment: Welcome to SO! My first guess would be that you have missing values - a missing value in `my_education` or both parent's education missing will result in a missing value in `achievement`.  In any case your second strategy is the right one - decide the right value of `achievement` or `advancement` in each line (could be +1, 0 -1), then sum over all cases (or by groups). `freq` command gives you the results in the output, if you want the results as data for further analysis look up `aggregate` function.

Answer (score 0):

IFs and COMPUTEs in SPSS operate on rows or cases in the data individually. In order to aggregate information across the cases you have to either tabulate the results from these individual case calculations via a procedure like FREQUENCIES or AGGREGATE, as suggested in the comments, or else add counter variables and use the LAG function to add things from the previous case.

The missing results are indeed, as suggested in the comments, probably due to missing data. Your EDIT2 should produce results for all cases if all three variables used in the IF statements are complete for every case.